# Style post differently

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been searching around and cannot find the right solution. My goal is to style the first post differently from the rest. I have them in a grid 3*3, and I want to first post to be fullwidth, add functions like date and category in that post.

CSS cannot be used.

The following piece of code is generating the loop in the index.php.

```
        <?php $i = 1; ?>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>                    

            <?php get_template_part('content','grid'); ?>                                          
            <?php if ($i%3 == 0) : ?>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <?php endif; $i++; ?>

        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); endif; ?>
```

I'm not sure how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can output the 1st post separately and then continue with the loop after:

```
<div class="first-post">
   <?php if (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
   <!-- calling the_post(); will step the loop forward -->
   <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
   <?php the_content() ?>
   <?php endif; ?> 
</div>


<div class="other-posts">
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>                    
        <!-- the loop will be at the 2nd post here -->
        <?php get_template_part('content','grid'); ?>                                          
        <?php if ($i%3 == 0) : ?>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <?php endif; $i++; ?>

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); endif; ?>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot andrew! Finally a solution that worked.

Comment: I have done the same myself in the past, when you want different content for the first post this is the easiest way. Glad it worked for you too

Comment: Is there any easy way as you know, to differently style ex the 3 or 5 post using this method or a similiar?

Comment: I think the simplest thing would be to check `$i` so eg `<?php if ($i == 3): ?> <div class="post-3">...</div> <?php elseif ($i==5): ?> <div class="post-5">...</div> <?php else: ?> <div class="other">...</div> <?php endif ?>`

Comment: Cool, thanks - it works! By using that IF I have replaced the spot for post number 3 with a custom div, but the post disappear. Do you know how that post in spot number 3 can be placed on spot post 4 instead? Much appreciated, I hope you learn something too!

Comment: well you could use `<?php if($i == 4): ?>` for post 4, don't forget you need to put the various output for that post in the if statement like `the_content()` etc

Comment: i have now this: <?php if ($i == 3): ?> <?php get_template_part('content','customdiv'); ?> <?php endif; ?> which replace the post number 3 with the content-customdiv.php. The output result is that the post that should be on that grid-position is hided. So now it's like this: Post 1, Post 2, Div, Post 4, Post 5.....

Do you know how this can be: Post 1, Post2, Div, **Post 3**, Post 4, Post 5...?

Comment: It looks like you are doing everything correct, my guess is there is a problem inside `content-customdiv.php` may I suggest that you raise a new question showing what you have so far, you'll get help from more people that way